# insert tow $_post in a column of database?

Tags: php, codeigniter

how can tow input `$_post` insert in a column of database?

```
"first name=George" and "last name=Kurdahi"   

$data = array('name' => $this -> input -> post('first_name') && $this -> input -> post('last_name'))
$this -> db -> insert('submits', $data)

Output: George Kurdahi
```

Comment: What database abstraction layer are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you wold like to insert "George Kurdahi" string to DB you should concatinate string with `.`

```
$data = array('name' => $this->input->post('first_name') . " " . $this->input->post('last_name'))
```

Or if you have 'name' and 'surname' fields in DB:

```
$data = array('name' => $this->input->post('first_name'), 'surname' => $this->input->post('last_name'))
```